# Why the package haskell-platform does not follow the proper version number?

Tags: debian, package-management, haskell

The package `haskell-platform` is a metapackage providing tools for developing in Haskell.

It is [self-distributed](https://www.haskell.org/platform/prior.html) with a versioning system using a version number, the release year and month. It is as well distributed on different distributions such as [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/en/buster/haskell-platform).

I could not gather how the Debian package number was made, since the latest on Buster is labeled as `2014.2.0.0.debian8`, which comes, e.g. with `ghc` >= 8.4.3. The problem is this `ghc` version is from 2018.

I was wondering if it was a deliberate choice from the packaging team or mislabeled from the website/documentation, since it seems that the packages provided by this metapackage.

I might have missed something, but I do not see the consistency here.